# php write tmp file to image

Tags: php, image

I am trying to covert the uploaded binary file into JPG format.

Here are the code.

```
 $uploaddir = '../images/upload_photo/';

 imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])), "tmp.jpg");
 move_uploaded_file("tmp.jpg", $uploaddir.$filename);
```

However, the output file is empty and fail to display any image, How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why are you creating a new image in the second line? That file is not a valid uploaded file so `move_uploaded_file()` will most likely not work with that. Just move `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` instead.

Comment: Try starting with this guide: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php